# C# Generic GDI+ Error when using Image.Save()

Tags: c#, windows, windows-xp, gdi+, tiff

I am a relative novice with imaging in C#. This is my first question on this board after a very long time of being a member. I hope it can help me get through this tricky scenario.

I need to read the contents (frames) of a Multi Page TIFF, saving each one into a List and finally returning it to then do some work with it.

Heres my code so far

```
public static  List<Image> GetAllPages(string file)
{
    images = new List<Image>();
    using (Image img = Image.FromFile(file))
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page); i++)
            {
                img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
                MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream();
                img.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);
                images.Add(Image.FromStream(byteStream));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return images;
}
```

**IMPORTANT** - This actually works like a charm when executing on Windows 7. However, when attempting the same on a Windows XP I get the seemedly well known Generic GDI+ error.

Is there anything obvious i am missing here? If not, would there be any other, more efficient way to return a list of images, extracted from a multi page tiff?

I would greatly appreciate any help anyone can give.

Comment: XP has an old version of GDI+, v1.00.  You've tested your code on v1.10, a much improved version.  Anything is possible, like you forgetting byteStream.Position = 0; have an affect.  To the specific TIFF, it is an acronym for Thousands of Incompatible File Formats.  Do us all a favor and stop supporting XP.

Comment: @HansPassant i did read about the GDI+ version scenario. I was hoping there was something obvious wrong that someone would be able to point out. I would love to stop supporting XP but unfortunately in this particular situation i am not the one that makes that choice.

I will test including the line you suggest however.

Comment: If anyone else could provide some further insight on this rather than simply resorting to telling me (and probably thousands of others with it) to stop supporting XP - i´d be extremely grateful!

Comment: @user3095888 Check if you have sufficient user rights in the directory in which you are saving the file eg: if in c:\ drive you will require admin rights.Try saving to another drive using the same code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 useful bits of information in the comment by Hans Passant. First, the TIFF format supports countless sub-types and variations not all of which are supported by GDI+.
Second, GDI+ was improved after XP, but not everywhere.

Your code does work on both Windows XP and Windows 7, but only with the right input TIFF files.

I tested it using .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 programs with 2 input files. The first file had 6 pages, all of which were encoded with LZW compression. This file worked on both Windows 7 and XP.

The second file had 11 pages with 11 different types of encoding. On Windows XP, only 7 pages out of 11 were loaded correctly.
On Windows 7, even fewer pages worked, but the JPEG compression in particular worked correctly although it failed under XP.

Windows 8.1 fared better than both and managed to load 8 pages correctly.

You can find the files along with a list of compression types used on this page:
http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/44475/ShowPost.aspx

Of course there are other TIFF sub-types, most of which are not supported by GDI+ natively, but these 11 are among the more common formats.

This leaves us with the problem of getting your files to work on Windows XP. Since they work on Windows 7, there's a strong possibility you have a TIF sub-type that works on Windows 7 but not XP such as JPEG compression. If that's the case, .NET alone will not be enough and you might have to use a dedicated imaging or TIFF library to load such files.

Comment: This was very helpful. Much appreciated. As it turned out, the issue was was with JPEG compression on files - XP/GDI1.0 didnt seem to like that. To overcome this, at least on the short term, ive arranged files to be created with LZW before they are to pass through my app.

Comment: A bonus advantage for using LZW is that unlike JPEG, it's lossless, which means pixel integrity doesn't degrade with repeated processing or saving. But one drawback is that it produces larger files than JPEG with most images.