# How to split a multi-frame TIFF image in pagewise in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#-2.0, tiff

I want to split multlipage tiff image in page wise.
I have written following code.

Dim pagecount, ImagePageCount As Integer
        Dim activePage As Integer
        Dim sourceImage As System.Drawing.Image = Nothing
        Dim fImage As Bitmap = Nothing
        Dim pageLoad As Boolean = False
        Try
            fImage = New Bitmap(tempFilePath)
            sourceImage = fImage

```
        pagecount = sourceImage.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page)
        pageLoad = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        pageLoad = False
        Throw
    End Try

    Try
        If pageLoad = True Then
            If pagecount <> 0 Then
                For ImagePageCount = 0 To pagecount - 1
                    sourceImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, ImagePageCount)
                    activePage = ImagePageCount + 1
                    Dim img1 As Drawing.Bitmap = CType(sourceImage.Clone, Drawing.Bitmap)
                    Dim tempPageFile As String = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2:00000000}_{3}.tif", Convert.ToString(indexEntry.GetFrameNumber()), Convert.ToString(indexEntry.GetCaseNumber()), document.ISN, activePage))
                    img1.Save(tempPageFile)
                    zip.AddFile(tempPageFile, "")
                Next
            End If
            sourceImage.Dispose()
            fImage.Dispose()

        End If
```

Mostly it works but when image with different size(in pixels) came that time sourceImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, ImagePageCount) fails.

I have observed that it happens only when first page's size is smaller than rest of the pages.

Any thoughts on this.

Thanks

Comment: TIFF is an acronym for Thousands of Incompatible File Formats.  The .NET codecs handle a reasonable subset, not thousands.  You'll have to go shopping for a library.

Comment: @HansPassant I have already purchased ABCpdf but that not worked in this case, I have only '.tif' format to support.

Answer (score 0):

The page size should not affect it. Testing similar code with a 3-page TIFF file where the first page was smaller than the other 2 worked in a .NET 2.0 program.
However, since TIFF can have a different compression format for each page, most likely the failure happens if you hit a page that's not supported by GDI+ on your operating system.
The test file that worked has all 3 pages saved with LZW compression.

See the following post for a discussion of how different Windows versions support different sub-types of TIFF:
[C# Generic GDI+ Error when using Image.Save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355389)