# Unsupported TIFF Compression

Tags: python, image, tiff, openslide

I'm using `openslide-python` to open a `svs` image, and I have run into the following issue:

```
>> import openslide as osi
>> a = osi.OpenSlide('image.svs')
```

yields the error

```
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 347 (0x15b) encountered.
image.svs: JPEG compression support is not configured.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/manan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openslide/__init__.py", line 154, in __init__
    self._osr = lowlevel.open(filename)
  File "/home/manan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openslide/lowlevel.py", line 178, in _check_open
    raise OpenSlideError(err)
openslide.lowlevel.OpenSlideError: Unsupported TIFF compression: 7
```

I haven't been able to find any solutions online for this issue; I've checked `libopenjpeg` and any additional relevant libraries to ensure they are at their latest respective versions.

Comment: You might want to file an issue at [their issue tracker](https://github.com/openslide/openslide-python/issues).

Comment: It appears the svs format is a variation of standard TIFF. If that's the case, TIFF files can contain images of various compression types. If other svs files work but not this one, the problem could be related to compression. For more details on TIFF compression sub-types, see the answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355389

Comment: Please provide the running environment means operating system, and libtiff, libjpeg versions

Comment: _Should_ be as simple as obtaining the TIFFlib source and compiling with all desired options configured.

Comment: If you don't mind sharing the slide (if you have the rights to it) that could help too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the code:
https://github.com/openslide/openslide/blob/7b99a8604f38280d14a34db6bda7a916563f96e1/src/openslide-vendor-generic-tiff.c#L222-L226

```
if (!TIFFIsCODECConfigured(compression)) {
  g_set_error(err, OPENSLIDE_ERROR, OPENSLIDE_ERROR_FAILED,
              "Unsupported TIFF compression: %u", compression);
  goto FAIL;
}
```

You will see that it uses `libtiff`: the function `TIFFIsCODECConfigured` is provided by the underlying `libtiff` library (see [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/TIFFIsCODECConfigured/)).

The compression tag is set to `7`; this is the uncommonly supported `JPEG ('new-style' JPEG)` compression scheme - sometimes also referred as `JPEG-in-TIFF`; which you need to install a codec for.

If you still have the slides and used e.g. Kodak Imaging, then you may be able to scan them again with a different compression; but that would be a back-and-around way. It probably is easier to try and add the codec and enable it in `libtiff`.

From [`libtiff` documentation](http://www.libtiff.org/internals.html):

> Support for JPEG compression is controlled by JPEG_SUPPORT. The JPEG codec that comes with libtiff is designed for use with release 5 or later of the Independent JPEG Group's freely available software distribution. This software can be retrieved from the directory ftp.uu.net:/graphics/jpeg/.

So the support is optional, and you may need to rebuild `libtiff` (see [instructions](http://www.libtiff.org/build.html)).

> By default JPEG support is not configured.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF
- http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/compression.html
- http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/faq.html
- http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tml.html#google
- https://web.archive.org/web/20160108212421/http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/TIFFTechNote2.html
- http://libtiff.maptools.org/
- http://www.asmail.be/msg0055223723.html
- http://www.alternatiff.com/resources/TIFFphotoshop.pdf
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/885938
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238249
- http://www.libtiff.org/build.html

Comment: Thank you for a superbly researched answer!